# sort by depth and children length js

Tags: javascript

i need to sort array of objects by depth of nested arrays inside objects
also i need to sort all levels with that logic + if depths same i need sort by children length. how can i do this?

maybe you know how to raise the maximum depth to the top level to make it easier
i tried to use recursive for loop through depths, but i cant understand what i need to do for raise depth on first level. Maybe this is the wrong approach, idk

for example:

```
[
  {
    value: '1',
    children: [
      {
        value: '1.1',
        children: [
          {
            value: '1.1.1',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: '1.2',
        children: [
          {
            value: '1.2.1',
            children: [
              {
                value: '1.2.1.1',
                children: []
              },
              {
                value: '1.2.1.2',
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: '1.3',
        children: [
          {
            value: '1.3.1',
            children: [
              {
                value: '1.3.1.1',
                children: [
                  {
                    value: '1.3.1.1.1',
                    children: []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
// result
[
  {
    value: '1',
    children: [
      {
        value: '1.3',
        children: [
          {
            value: '1.3.1',
            children: [
              {
                value: '1.3.1.1',
                children: [
                  {
                    value: '1.3.1.1.1',
                    children: []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: '1.2',
        children: [
          {
            value: '1.2.1',
            children: [
              {
                value: '1.2.1.1',
                children: []
              },
              {
                value: '1.2.1.2',
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: '1.1',
        children: [
          {
            value: '1.1.1',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: optimized the sort function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate depth recursively, then sort by depth recursively and delete the depth property:

```js
const children = [{
    value: '1',
    children: [
        {
            value: '1.1',
            children: [
                {
                    value: '1.1.1',
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            value: '1.2',
            children: [
                {
                    value: '1.2.1',
                    children: [
                        {
                            value: '1.2.1.1',
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            value: '1.2.1.2',
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            value: '1.3',
            children: [
                {
                    value: '1.3.1',
                    children: [
                        {
                            value: '1.3.1.1',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    value: '1.3.1.1.1',
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];

function setDepth(children, depth = 0) {
    for (const child of children) {
        child.depth = setDepth(child.children, depth);
    }
    const maxDepth = Math.max(0, ...children.map(child => child.depth));
    return maxDepth + +Boolean(children.length);
}

function sort(children) {

    children.sort((a, b) => b.depth - a.depth || b.children.length - a.children.length);

    for(const child of children){
        sort(child.children);
        delete child.depth;
    }
}

setDepth(children);
sort(children);

console.log(JSON.stringify(children, null, 4));
```

Comment: how can i sort every level of depth with it? sorry, my example wasn't full. i want to sort every depth with same logic. for example if level 2 has 2 childs, child with more depth goin upper

Comment: @syncilya it should sort all levels deep